# Stop Magento sending auto invoice after completed payment

Tags: magento, paypal, payment, invoice

The thing is, I want to send them manually via the API because in my country a invoice is a legal-bound order.
Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the accepted answer is the best possible way to handle the problem. If you disable the automatic transactional emails completely from the backend, you also can't trigger them manually or use them in your custom module anymore. That means you have to create every transactional email you disabled from scratch if you need to send it at another point as magento standart, which also is a considerable maintenance effort in the aftermath.

The solution I came up with is to programmatically disable sending the email on invoice creation and leverage the default sender classes in a custom observer event. In our case we wanted to send the invoice email when shipment is created.

You do that by overriding \Magento\Sales\Model\InvoiceOrder. Locate the line

```
$this->notifierInterface->notify($order, $invoice, $comment);
```

And remove it. 
If you want to trigger the email, you can still do that from anywhere you want using the standard "send" function from the InvoiceSender. In our case, we trigger the email from observer like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender;

class SendInvoiceWithShipment implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_invoiceSender;

    public function __construct(
        InvoiceSender $invoiceSender
    ) {
        $this->_invoiceSender = $invoiceSender;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getShipment()->getOrder();
        $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
             // this is where the magic happens
             $this->_invoiceSender->send($invoice);
        }               


    }
}
```

Observer is triggered by event sales_order_shipment_save_after

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name='sales_order_shipment_save_after'>
        <observer name='SendInvoiceWithShipment' instance='Vendor\Module\Observer\SendInvoiceWithShipment'
        />
    </event>
</config>
```

You can do this for every transactional email.

Comment: ...but you realize that the question was asked for Magento 1, right? ;) Your solution is good, but only works in Magento 2.

Comment: This solution also prevent Order email as well

Comment: @DushyantJoshi Since only invoice model is altered all other transactional mails should work fine. Did you double check config?

Comment: @Tobi by commenting `$this->notifierInterface->notify($order, $invoice, $comment);` it is even sending invoice email as well.

Answer (score 5):

Go to System->Configuration->Sales Emails and disable "Invoice".

Comment: Sorry that's not it. It just does not send the emails anymore but still creates them and still sets the status to "completed" which is wrong.

Comment: Okay, but that was your question :) Ask a new one, then